# Significantly changed question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

A user asked this question:
[What would you call a person who is obsessed with being "normal"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378841/what-would-you-call-a-person-who-is-obsessed-with-being-normal)

In the text body they asked for:

> "someone who cannot bear to be different from other people"

and got plenty of good answers for this.

They then edited it to give an example which doesn't seem to touch on normality, and changed it to be about somebody wanting someone *else* to be different.

This late change completely invalidates answers with a +80 score!

I've voted to close as "unclear what you're asking". Am I doing the right thing? I'm now thinking that I should possibly revert the addition of the example, and request to the user that if they want to ask a substantially different question from the original one, they should ask it as a new question.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. The question in its current form complies with the [tag:single-word-requests] policy, and is clearer than it was before. The way it was before did not. We usually close questions as unclear for the purposes of compelling such a change, so penalizing the improvement seems contrary to the purpose of policy. It should have been closed earlier for lacking a contextual sentence, so that the overrated and premature answers would not have been made. It's almost funny in a way though, the one time we have plenty of nouns, the questioner wanted an adjective…

Comment: @Tonepoet - :o I didn't even notice that they'd stated adjective in the edit! I still thought they were looking for a noun. Wow. Sometimes I think that questions are clear enough even without an example sentence, and then we go and get a question like this! With hindsight I completely agree it should have been closed earlier.